# Array.Copy and accessing string array with variable

Tags: c#

I've tried several things and just cannot seem to get this. I have 10 MotorReply strings that I then split into array elements. Then I want to copy those elements to another array so I can loop through again but whatever I try, I can't access the BayReplyArray by using the incrementing i variable, i.e.  BayReplyArray[i]

Declarations:

```
    string[] MotorReplyArray = new string[30];
    string[] BayReplyArray1 = new string[30];
    string[] BayReplyArray2 = new string[30];
    string[] BayReplyArray3 = new string[30];
    up to 10

    int j = 0;

     for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
     {
        //  here we take the Motor? reply string for each bay and split the parameters into individual string arrays
        char[] delimiters = new char[] { '\r', ':' };
        MotorReplyArray = MotorReply[i].Split(delimiters);
        foreach (string line in MotorReplyArray)
        {
           // trim whitespace from ends
           MotorReplyArray[j] = line.Trim();
           j++;
        }
        Array.Copy(MotorReplyArray, BayReplyArray[i], j);
        Array.Clear(MotorReplyArray, 0, j);
        j = 0;
     }
```

Comment: Why are you updating the array you are doing the `foreach` over? That could cause some issues.

Comment: @JBKing: Updating elements in a sequence is allowed, so long as you're not inserting or deleting elements from the underlying collection.  Since it's a fixed-size array anyway...

Comment: @EE_Kraig: Why are you copying arrays?  You would almost certainly want to simply populate a new array and return that from your method instead.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: After reading your comment, I think I see what you mean.    BayReplyArray[i] = MotorReply[i].Split(delimiters);

Comment: I'm new to SE, but why is this off-topic? Isn't this what this site is for??

Comment: Implementation specific work would belong on StackOverflow.com and not here where conceptual questions tend to be more common.

Comment: Ahhh, I was just wondering what the difference between the sites was!

Comment: @EE_Kraig - your indexing of `BayReplyArray` in `Array.Copy` call is off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't access the BayReplyArray by using the incrementing i variable, i.e. BayReplyArray[i]

You seem to think that if `i` is `1` then `BayReplyArray[i]` is the same as `BayReplyArray1`, which  is not the case.  You can easily enough change to a jagged array:

```
string[] MotorReplyArray = new string[30];
string[][] BayReplyArray = new string[][10];
```

now `BayReplyArray[i]` is a string array and you can use `Array.Copy` on it.